# What do you do to a interface with a nullable type that is no longer nullable?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a customer:

```
interface Customer {
  name: string,
  age: number | null
}
```

But I loop over all customers and filter out nullable values for age.

I don't want a null check through my codebase if I know now that this field isn't null.

So I have to create a new type.

```
interface CustomerAgeNotNull {

}
```

Is there a simpler way of maintaining and managing this types of interfaces? I could imagine n number of interfaces for any interface.

**Update, Tried what is below:**

```
type ExcludePropType<T, R> = {
  [k in keyof T]: Exclude<T[k], R>
}

type Customer = {
  name: string,
  age: number | null,
  dolphin: string | null
}

type CustomerAgeNotNull = ExcludePropType<Customer, null>

const v = function (): CustomerAgeNotNull {
  return {
    name: 'Thomas', 
    age: 12,
    dolphin: null,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Exclude type R from properties in T.
 */
export type ExcludePropType<T, R> = {
  [k in keyof T]: Exclude<T[k], R>
}
```

Usage:

```
type CustomerAgeNotNull = ExcludePropType<Customer, null>
```

UPDATE:

This requires `strictNullCheck` (part of `strict`) to be enabled.

Without `strickNullCheck`, the type `string` and `number` includes `null`.
So it is not possible to exclude `null` from the type.

Comment: Do you have a better name than `UnNull`? I will put this into `type-plus`

Comment: Added in `type-plus@1.9.0`

Comment: bonus: if you `Customer` interface will not be used to implement class, prefer using type alias `type Customer = { ... }`

Comment: This is still allowing the new type `CustomerAgeNotNull` properties that are null to be null, updated above.

Comment: Updated answer. You need to turn on `strictNullCheck`.